# How to install google chrome on Centos 7

Tags: linux, google-chrome, centos-7

After hours of searching i was finally able to install and run googlechrome on centos 7.

1)Where to download ?

```
#1) download chrome rpm from https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/
```

at the time of writing this it is version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit)

2) Installation

```
Go to your downloads directory and install the rpm(you need to be root user)

#cd ~/Downloads
#ls 
google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
...

#yum install google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

3) Install nss
# yum install nss
```

Running chrome without installing "nss" will give below error in terminal..

[7:7:1011/133301:ERROR:nss_util.cc(209)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023

```
[ Steps below do not require the user to be root ]

4) Remove users google-chrome profile (new profile will be automagically created in the next run)

$ rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/

5) To-start chrome

$ google-chrome &
```

Comment: It's fine to write answers/howtos yourself, but please still do so in the **question & answer format**, like everything else. (Also clean up the formatting a little bit...)

Comment: I've made changes, hope its readable